# Proving that if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and that the image of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$\ $\mathbb{Q}$, then $f$ is a constant function

Tags: analysis, continuity, solution-verification

I was asked to prove that for a function $f$ that is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, whose image is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ \ $\Bbb{Q}$, $f$ is a constant function.

My proof goes as follows:

Suppose for a contradiction that f is not constant, so there exists $x_1$ $\neq$ $x_2$ so that $f(x_1)$ $\neq$ $f(x_2)$, say, $x_1$,$x_2$ $\in$ $\Bbb{Q}$.
Now, f is continuous at c for every c $\in$ $\Bbb{R}$, so $f_{[x_1,x_2]}$:[$x_1$,$x_2$] $\to$ $\Bbb{R}$ is continuous at c for every c $\in$ [$x_1$,$x_2$].

Consider $v \in \Bbb{Q}$ and $v \in (f(x_1),f(x_2))$, which exists by completeness of the set of real numbers.
There exists $x_0 \in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(x_0)=v \in \Bbb{Q}$, by the intermediate value theorem.
A contradiction, since the image of $f$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ \ $\Bbb{Q}$.

So $f$ is a constant function. $\square$

I feel there is an easier way, to prove this; nevertheless, what do you think of my proof, does it hold ?
Thank you!

Comment: This is a little more verbose than I would present it, but overall good. The one thing I will say is that you do not need to presume $x_1$ and $x_2$ are rational. You do not use that anywhere in your argument, so it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the proof that came to mind when I read your question, and you expressed it well - except I would say that $v$ exists by density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you very much ! By the way, are the expressions "completeness of the real numbers" and "density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ not interchangeable" ?

Comment: No, it's not the same, as @NerdOnTour stated. Completeness of $\mathbb R$ or any other space makes no reference to any subset of the space. They are distinct, in some sense complimentary properties. We can have complete metric spaces which aren't separable (no countable dense subset), hence the need, often, to assert "let $X$ be a complete AND separable metric space" (Polish space).

Answer (score 3):

The proof is good and – as far as I can see – the "go to" proof.
There are a few mistakes I'd like to point out:

1. You assume that $x_1, x_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$. This is not necessary for your further proof (as [Cameron](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/22551/cameron-williams) already pointed out in a comment). And it is also not possible to assume this without loss of generality: Why should they be rational?
2. Completeness of the real numbers does not yield a rational $v \in (f(x_1), f(x_2))$. As [toe-pose](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/411883/toe-pose) points out in their answer, what you need is density of $\mathbb{Q}$.
   Completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ is not the same as density of $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$. However $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$; maybe this confused you?
3. For the intervals $(x_1, x_2)$ and $(f(x_1), f(x_2))$ to make sense, you assume silently that $x_1 < x_2$ and $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$. When proceeding as detailed as you did, you could be more explicit about that. While the assumption $x_1 < x_2$ can be arranged without loss of generality, the second one need not hold. You can do a case distinction, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did misunderstood what "completeness" and "density" each meant.
And yes, that assumption was useless, I guess I it was part of the draft I had in mind for the proof and I forgot to scrap it.
I thought about saying that f(x_1)<f(x_2), but I felt like the generality would not hold, as you said, I could have shown multiple cases; I'll be more careful next time
Thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that came to my mind is the following one:

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, $f(\mathbb{R})$ is connected. Consider $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x\neq y$. If $f(x)\neq f(y)$, we can assume without loss of generality that $f(x)<f(y)$. Then, since $f$ is continuous, $f([x,y]\bigcup[y,x])$ must be an interval (since it has to be connected), so $[f(x),f(y)]\subset f([x,y]\bigcup[y,x])\subset f(\mathbb{R})$ and since is a non-trivial interval, $\exists q\in\mathbb{Q}:q\in[f(x),f(y)]\subset f(\mathbb{R})$ so $f(\mathbb{R})\nsubseteq\mathbb{R}\diagdown\mathbb{Q}$ and we've reached a contradiction because we assumed there were in fact $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x\neq y$ and $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

This proof (if correct) can be extended to $f(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathbb{Q}$ and $f$ being continuous.